# Is it possible to reference existing source files in C# Roslyn Code Generation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-generation, roslyn

So consider the case where I have a class `ClassA` inside of the project that is currently being generated into:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(int a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say that I wanted to automatically create an extension method for ClassA, something like:

```
public static class ClassAExtensions
{
    public static ClassA Double(this ClassA classA)
    {
        return new ClassA(classA.A * 2);
    }
}
```

When trying to create this source code using the new source code generators, the compilation can't seem to find `ClassA`. I've tried adding the namespace of `ClassA` into the generated document and setting the namespace of the generated extension method class to the namespace directly to that of ClassA, but neither seem to be able to see it:

`The type of namespace 'ClassA' does not exist in the namespace 'ClassANamespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

So the final questions are:

- **Is there some trick to making the code generation compiler be able to see my non-generated code?**
- **Is this even possible right now?**
- **Is there a workaround to get something like this to work?**

Many of the samples provided declare the class being modified `partial`, but I don't particularly like this for what I'm trying to do.

I've also looked into adding an assembly reference, though my understanding was that the code being generated should be included and compiled alongside the existing code. Also, if this code is being compiled before my "production" code, then adding an assembly reference would not be possible and/or this would create a circular reference.

Comment: You can reference a compiled assembly (dll file usually) in your project without any problem, the sole requirement is to be a c# assembly (not "native" assembly) and version compatible, and it should work IMHO. Furthermore, if you want a real "extension method" consider use "this" keyword in method argument.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in the sample. 'this' keyword was added. And based on my understanding of the pipeline, the assembly is not yet compiled by the time the source code generator runs its compilation. That is, ClassA is in the same project that I'm editing/analyzing with the source code generation. Adding some comments to this effect in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files added in a source generator act like regular files from the perspective of the rest of the language rules so yes you can absolutely reference classes in the user's code as long as you're qualifying them correctly. It sounds like you have a bug; if there's still a specific problem you may want to try creating a project that contains both the input file and also the source generated output; you should see the same error and then can figure out what's up.

Comment: Ah, it turns out I did and this test helped show me what the issue was! I had defined the class that I wanted to use was nested inside of another class, and `ClassDeclarationSyntax.Identifier` it seems does not have the full name there. Do you know if there's an easy way to detect when a class is nested using the `ClassDeclarationSyntax`? I know how to do it with reflection, but I presume there is a way. Maybe walking up its parent and determining if that is a ClassDeclarationSyntax as well? I bet I can just make a simple helper that can walk up until it hits a namespace... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: One option is to walk the tree; the other option is to call SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol() with the class declaration and then try to work from there.

Comment: I use the `ISymbol.ToDisplayString()` method which returns the fully qualified type name (including generic argument).